# SQLite DATETIME to Postgres migration

Tags: postgresql, sqlite, date

I have a field in SQLite defined as

```
ended DATETIME default 0
```

We are porting to Postgres, which would be the most appropriate type in Postgres ... timestamp with or without timezone?

currently the enddate holds values like 1477330116408

Comment: SQLite doenst store timezone within DATETIME field i would say timestamp without timezone.

Comment: `1477330116408` is not a valid timestamp value to begin with (at least not in SQL)

Comment: @RaymondNijland tnx, what would be the correct way to port this type of data from sqllite to postgre timestamp field? probbably i have to use some function to transform 1477330116408 to timestamp?